# AltBeacon: ranging not working as expected

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am building an Android App, which should start actions in the **background**, when the user enters or leaves a "bluetooth zone", which the user can define. Like Geofencing from Google.

I have read a lot here and adapted the code, how I thought, it have to be.

The "bluetooth zones" are configured by the user, by scanning the bluetooth devices, choosing the device and adding a radius to it. This workes as expected. 
This "bluetooth zone" is then persisted and ranged by the BeaconManager as a region in an own activity:

```
    BeaconManager mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    Region singleBeaconRegion = new Region(mRegion.getText().toString(), listB);
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(singleBeaconRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
```

Also I have an Application, which looks like this:

```
    public class BtZoneApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier{
private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceAppl";
private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;
private Region mAllBeaconsRegion;
private BackgroundPowerSaver mBackgroundPowerSaver;
private RegionBootstrap mRegionBootstrap;
private Worker worker;
private final static String ALLBEACONSREGION = "##AllBeaconsRegion##";
DbServerHelper datasourceServer;
DbZoneHelper datasource;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region(ALLBEACONSREGION, null, null, null);
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000L);
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2100L);
   // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
    mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
}

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    // Start actions
    if (region.getUniqueId().equals(ALLBEACONSREGION)){
        return;
    }
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon "+beacon.toString() + " is about " + beacon.getDistance() + " meters away, with Rssi: " + beacon.getRssi());
            // 
            if (beacon.getDistance() < radius && !status) {
                // set status to true
                // start action at entering zone
            }
            // radius * 2 for testing
            if (beacon.getDistance() > radius * 2 && status) {
                // set status to false
                // start action at exiting zone
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
   // do nothing
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "entered region.  starting ranging");
    setRegionsAtBoot();
    mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
   // do nothing. Ranging should work further
}

// Set regions to monitor at boot/startup
private void setRegionsAtBoot(){
    ...
    for (Iterator<SimpleBeacon> iterator = beacons.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        ...
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(simpleBeacon.getId(), listB));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that it does not start ranging at start of the app, allthough the BluetoothLeScanner sees the device. Then sometime it starts suddenly. It is a strange behavior.

When it runs then the entering/exiting is reported multiple times, even the device is not moving and often the entering/exiting is not reported (in time?) in the background.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues in the `Application` code:

- There is no need to implement `BeaconConsumer` or call `bind` explicitly when using `RegionBootstrap`, as binding happens automatically inside `RegionBootstrap`.
- I would move the call to `setRegionsAtBoot` to `didEnterRegion`.

It is not totally clear why the symptoms you describe would happen, but the above may be contributors.

You might also use an off the shelf scanner like Locate Beacon to make sure your beacons can be ranged reliably.  This would help eliminate a hardware issue.

Finally, get it working in the foreground first, then focus on background operations.

Comment: I tested the beacon with the Locate app and it found it. So I searched more and in end it was my fault. I had a bug at reading from the database and so the constructed regions were wrong. Sorry! 

I also updated the code, how you proposed. Thanks.

It works now in foreground, but in background it takes a lot of time to recognize the ranging. 
I setted the background scan times like:
`       mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000L);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2100L);
`
Am I missing something?

Comment: On Android 5+ devices detections are much faster in the background.  But on earlier version of the OS you have to throttle background scans to save battery, unless you have a specialized app were high battery background use is OK.  You have to decide on the balance between slow background detections and saving battery based on the needs of your use case.

Comment: as you suggested I moved the initialization of the beacons from the database to didEnterRegion: setRegionsAtBoot to didEnterRegion.
The problem I saw now is, that didEnterRegion is called often and then the regions are registered multiple times in the rangedRegions ArrayList at startRangingBeaconsInRegion of BeaconManager. Also then when I do stopRangingBeaconsInRegion for one region, it deletes only one of the duplicates. Wouldn't here be better to use an other list which avoids duplicate elements?

Comment: You might simply call stopRangingBeaconsInRegion before calling startRangingBeaconsInRegion.  And keep your unique identifier consistent.